# AngularJS - problems with angularJS route

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm having a problem with angularJs, basically when I press the link it doesn't change the page, can someone please help me?

```js
//   app.js

var app = angular.module("geral", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider) 
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', 
    {
        controller: "HomeController",
        templateUrl: "App/Views/home.html"
    })
    .when('/secondPage', 
    {
        controller: "SecondController",
        templateUrl: "App/Views/second.html"
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' })
});


// HomeController.js

app.controller("HomeController", ["$scope", function($scope) 
{
    $scope.persons = 
    [
        {
            name: "...",
            age: 18
        },
        {
            name: "...",
            age: 82
        }
    ];
}]);


// SecondController.js

app.controller("SecondController", ["$scope", function($scope) 
{
    $scope.temp = setInterval(function() 
    {
        if (parseInt($("#circle").css("top")) + parseInt($("#circle").css("height")) < window.innerHeight)
            $("#circle").css("top", (parseInt($("#circle").css("top")) + 1).toString() + "px");
        else clearInterval($scope.temp);
    }, 10);
}]);
```

```html
<!--Index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" type="type/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="Content/geral.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/Shared/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Shared/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="geral">
        <div ng-view></div>
        <script src="Scripts/Shared/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Shared/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Shared/knockout.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Shared/geral.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/Controllers/SecondController.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


<!--home.html-->

<div>
    <div class="container" ng-repeat="person in persons">
        <span class="info">{{ person.name }}</span><br />
        <span class="info">{{ person.age | number }}</span><hr />
    </div>
    <a href="#/secondPage">Start cicle</a>
</div>

<!--second.html-->

<div class="main">
    <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

I don't believe the problem is in the controllers script, because I have already inverted the roles of controllers and the one related to '/' works fine.
By the way, the point is to make a single page application.

Comment: dude this is not helping create a minimum [plunk](http://plnkr.co) or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your problem

Comment: waht else do you want me to put here?

Comment: do you want more information about the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see the problem is with `href` in your anchor tag.

try changing this,

```
<a href="#/secondPage">Start cicle</a>
```

to

```
<a href="#secondPage">Start cicle</a>
```

Take a look at this example [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/CjocbxTQczLjLOqHDdJl?p=preview)

Comment: yes the problem was the anchor, i had '#/secondPage' so I changed it to '#!/secondPage' and now it works, thanks :)

Comment: i just don't know why the url changes to '.../index.html#!/' instead of '.../index.html#/', any idea why it adds an exclamation point to the url?

Comment: I don't actually remember this but I think its angular convention to add `!` to the url. although you only need to put `href="#secondPage"` not `href="#!/secondPage"`